# How does this Switch statement know which case to execute? (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

Here is a code form a PHP+MySQL book I am reading and I am having trouble understanding this code. This code is about checking a file uploaded into a database. (Please excuse any spelling errors if any, I was typing it in)

Q1: How does it know which case to echo? In the whole code, there is no mention of each case.

Q2: Why do they skip case 5?! Or does it not matter which numbers you use(so I can have case 1, case 18, case 2?)

For this statement, can you say if($_FILES['userfile']['error']=1) instead of >0? Are they the same thing?

```
    if($_FILES['userfile']['error']>0)
{
    echo 'Problem: ';
switch($_FILES['userfile']['error'])
{
    case 1: echo 'File exceeded upload_max_filesize';
            break;
    case 2: echo 'File exceeded max_file_size';
            break;
    case 3: echo 'File only partially uploaded';
            break;
    case 4: echo 'No file uploaded';
            break;
    case 6: echo 'Cannot upload file: no temp directory specified';
            break;
    case 7: echo 'Upload failed: Cannot write to disk';
            break;
}
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This should help](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php):

> **UPLOAD_ERR_OK Value: 0**; There is no
> error, the file uploaded with success.
>
> **UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE Value: 1**; The
> uploaded file exceeds the
> upload_max_filesize directive in
> php.ini.
>
> **UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE Value: 2**; The
> uploaded file exceeds the
> MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was
> specified in the HTML form.
>
> **UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL Value: 3**; The
> uploaded file was only partially
> uploaded.
>
> **UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE Value: 4**; No file
> was uploaded.
>
> **UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR Value: 6**;
> Missing a temporary folder. Introduced
> in PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.3.
>
> **UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE Value: 7**; Failed
> to write file to disk. Introduced in
> PHP 5.1.0.
>
> **UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION Value: 8**; A PHP
> extension stopped the file upload. PHP
> does not provide a way to ascertain
> which extension caused the file upload
> to stop; examining the list of loaded
> extensions with phpinfo() may help.
> Introduced in PHP 5.2.0.

The gist of it is that when you are handling an uploaded file, you check the error value (`$_FILES['userfile']['error']`) to see the status of the file. The switch statement just breaks it down by checking the possible error codes that could be present. These are basically "hardwired".

Comment: Ahh, so these are "defaults" and you just got to use them correct?
Thanks

Comment: Yes. They are pretty much hard-wired so it's safe to code against them.

Answer (score 2):

All of the error cases for file uploads are predefined in PHP. You can see their meanings here:
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 0):

$_FILES['userfile']['error'] is just a number. The switch statement goes to the `case` that matches the number. So it's like a big list of `if(...){goto ...;}` statements. I'm guessing case 5 either never happens or doesn't matter.